# Can this Migrate from Azure Devops to a TFS environment?

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

It might sound backwards, but we have a need to move a Azure Devops project of epic's, User stores tasks etc, as well as all existing comments, links, and dependencies to a TFS environment, can this tool do that?

Comment: [This](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/586312/migrating-azure-devops-services-to-on-premise-tfs.html) might help. Good luck.

Comment: Defo don't use the TFS Integration Tools or OpsHub!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can using the Azure DevOps Migration Tools.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration